# Sending custom values on save and update using Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik grid in my asp.net mvc application that looks something like:

[image: Screenshot]

Now it lists all the regions in a zone selected from the list placed just above the grid. zoneid is foreign key in the grid. Now I want that when I add new region in the grid the zoneID should be taken from the list instead of what is present in zone column of the grid because that value is just to display the zone and that can also be removed from the grid as it as apparent from the list which zone the listed regions belong to.

I understand that I could have used editor templates to show this list inside the grid on edit but I prefer it to be outside the grid and provide some filtering on basis of the zone as we are likely to have many regions per zone. so my concern here, now, is how can I set ZoneID of a region (edited or newly added) equal to selected value of list that shows just above the grid control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by hooking the onSave event of Telerik grid like

```
<%
Html.Telerkik.Grid<xyz.company>()
.Name("name")
.// other properties
.Events(even=>even.onSave("onSave")
.Render();%>
```

Inside onSave event handler in JS I have written something like

```
function onSave(e)
{
    var data = e.values;
    data["companyID"] = $("#CompanySelectList").val();
    e.values = data;
    return true;
}
```

onSave event adds the companyID at companyID index of json that will be submitted to the server and modelbinder will bind it with concerning property name of model.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the AddNewRecord button, why don't you set the Value of your zone equals to the zoneId selected in the combobox value ?

I've done something a little similar, but I had to get the value from a Treeview.

```
    private void btnAddContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int64 companyId = Int64.Parse(treeCompany.SelectedNode.Name);

        dsSociete.ContactRow newContact = dsSociete.Contact.NewContactRow();
        newContact.SocieteId = societeId;
        dsSociete.Contact.AddContactRow(newContact);
    }
```

And once i add a new Contact, it gets automatically its Company (Societe is Company in French) set.

I did it in Winform, but I guess you can do the same in Web?

Comment: man it seems like web forms. i need to do it in asp.net mvc and all that i have to write in javascript. i m struggling to find some event of telerik grid on client side that i can hook. however, it was nice to know some French :)

Comment: @Muhammad Ok, thanks for having written the solution ! Haha, about French, well I'm definitely waiting for the French Language StackExchange forum to be a little more useful ;) Good luck to you for the rest of your project :)

Comment: don't u think shifting to french language exchange will decrease ur readership and number of people benefiting from ur expertise.